# How to specify mono program-options arguments when using supervisord?

Tags: mono, supervisor

We're using the Linux `supervisord` to manage a service that runs under mono. This is on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS with `supervisord` v3.0b2.

I'm trying to figure out how to specify a mono *program-options* argument so that it is recognized when the command is invoked by the Supervisor.

The mono help says the command format is:

```
mono [options] program [program-options]
```

In the config file for the service */etc/supervisor/conf.d/myservice.conf*, I've tried both of these formats and neither work.  The service starts, however ignores the `-abc` argument:

```
command=mono --gc=sgen MyService.exe -abc
command=mono --gc=sgen MyService.exe -- -abc
```

If I run the first command at the shell, it works (the `-abc` argument is recognized and logged during service startup):

```
mono --gc=sgen MyService.exe -abc
```

Note that I use *sudo supervisorctl reread* whenever I modify the service's config file.  Here is the complete file:

```
[program:myservice]
environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
command=mono --gc=sgen MyService.exe -- -abc
user=myuser
stderr_logfile=/var/log/myservice/myservice-err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/myservice/myservice-stdout.log
directory=/opt/myservice
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot this problem, I decided to enable debug logging for the `supervisord` process so I could hopefully see what command it parsed from *myservice.conf*.

I added the line `loglevel=debug` to the `supervisord` section of */etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf*.  I then tailed 
*/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log* and restarted the service with `sudo service supervisor restart` and saw that the myservice command argument was now being recognized!

BTW, I had changed back to use the command format:

```
command=mono --gc=sgen MyService.exe -abc
```

So, for some reason `supervisorctl reread` wasn't enough, I had to restart the `supervisord` service.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Seams that you have to restart the supervisor process to activate options changes. Btw. you can see which options are currently active with `systemctl status supervisor`. This will include processes started by supervisor!